# Topology of some subsets of $\mathbb R^{n}$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $A,B$ be two subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, considered, with the Euclidean metric. I want to show the following:
$1)$ If A is open, and $B$ is arbitrary, then $A+B$ is open.

$2)$ If A and B are compact then so is $A+B$.

$3)$ If A compact, and B closed, then $A+B$ is closed.

For 2, let $x_{n}=a_{n}+b_{n}$ be a sequence in $A+B$, where $a_{n} \in A$ and $b_{n} \in B$. Since $A$ is compact, we can find $a_{n_{k}}$ subsequence of $a_{n}$ converging to $a \in A$. Consider $b_{n_{k}}$. Since B is compact, we can find a convergent subsequence $b_{n_{k_{q}}}$ converging to $b \in B$. Hence $x_{n_{k_{q}}}$ converges to $a+b \in A+B$. Now for $3$, let $x_{n}=a_{n}+b_{n}$ is a sequence in $A+B$ converging to $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $a_{n_{k}}$ be a convergent subsequence of $a_{n}$ to $a \in A$. Hence, $b_{n_{k}}=x_{n_{k}}-a_{n_{k}}$ converges to $x-a$. B closed so $x-a \in B$. Hence $x-a+a=x \in A+B$ so $A+B$ closed. Any hints for 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Show that if $A$ is open, then $A+\{x\}$ is open for any $x\in\mathbb R^n$.

Then write $A+B$ as the union of open sets.